# Spring WebClient aggregates multiple 401 UNAUTHORIZED error to throw Exceptions.CompositeException

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

When WebClient calls an external api (with different query params) asynchronously with a wrong token, the first few returns with 401 UNAUTHORIZED and the control flow stops with `Exceptions.CompositeException`. We've a filter like below added to the `WebClient` instance that checks for 4xx and 5xx response status code to throw a custom exception

```java
private final ExchangeFilterFunction responseFilter() {
    return ExchangeFilterFunction
            .ofResponseProcessor(response -> response.statusCode().isError() ? error(() -> new CustomException("API Error")) : just(response));

private WebClient buildWebClient(WebClient.Builder builder) {
    return builder
            .filter(responseFilter())
            .build();
}
```

Now the issue is `CustomException` doesn't get thrown when the first call returns with an error (401) but rather aggregates a bunch of calls and throws `Exceptions.CompositeException`. In the logs we can see atleast 3 or 4 `401 UNAUTHORIZED` before Composite failure. It doesn't throw the expected `CustomException` when the first one fails. This WebClient call happens inside a `Flux.zip` and I'm not sure whether that has something to do with the issue.

Comment: can you share the code that makes the web client call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using any of the `DelayError` variant operators, reactor will collect any exceptions (if there this more than 1) into a `CompositeException`.

Reactor provide a utility method `Exceptions.unwrapMultiple` to help unpack a composite exception into a list of throwables if you want to only propagate a subset or single error upstream - [java docs](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/Exceptions.html#unwrapMultiple-java.lang.Throwable-)

***Exceptions.unwrapMultiple***

> Attempt to unwrap a Throwable into a List of Throwables. This is only done on the condition that said Throwable is a composite exception built by multiple(Throwable...), in which case the list contains the exceptions wrapped as suppressed exceptions in the composite. In any other case, the list only contains the input Throwable (or is empty in case of null input).

***Example***

Below is a small example using `unwrapMultiple` to propagate only the first `Throwable` within the `CompositeException`.

```java
    Flux<Object> range = Flux.range(1, 10)
            .flatMapDelayError(i -> Mono.error(new IllegalArgumentException(String.format("Error: %s", i))), 10, 1)
            .onErrorResume(throwable -> Mono.error(Exceptions.unwrapMultiple(throwable).get(0)));
    StepVerifier.create(range)
            .expectError(IllegalArgumentException.class)
            .verify();
```

Comment: Yes, I added an additional condition to check first whether the exception is of type `Composite` by using `Exceptions.isMultiple` and proceeded with `Exceptions.unwrapMultiple`

Comment: @VivekTS you should not need to perform a check via `Exceptions.isMultiple` as this check is already done inside `Exceptions.unwrapMultiple`.